# How to disable back button in certain page in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I have splash screen then it goes to main page. After main page, there are many pages too.*

*what I want is that user can go back with back button however he / she can not use back button in main page to go splash screen. How Can I do that ?*

*When I use this in Main page, in all pages  back button doesnt work*

```
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
      return true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can use **switch navigator** instead of using event listeners.

Comment: How your screen routes working ? I mean the control flow

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the EventListner.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
```

}

Comment: componentWillUnmount() not working when I navigate other screen why ? forexample componentWillUnmount()  in Main screen, I navigate Main2 from Main 
like  this.props.navigation.navigate('Main2') however componentWillUnmount() which is in Main not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the screen is focused or not. Depending on that, BackHandler listener should be added or removed.

If you don't remove the listener and navigate to another screen from the same Stack navigator, it will be reflected to a new screen.

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    'hardwareBackPress',
    this.backPressHandler,
  );
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const {isFocused} = this.props.navigation;
  if (prevProps.isFocused !== isFocused) {
    if (isFocused) {
      this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        this.backPressHandler,
      );
    } else {
      this.backHandler.remove();
    }
  }
}

OR

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.backHandler.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below given code to all the screens and set backBtnDisable to true in case you want to disable back button.

```
componentDidMount() 
{
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUnMount()
{
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {

  if(this.state.backBtnDisable)
  {
    return true;
  } 
  else
  {
    return false
  }
}
```